What is the real form of p-type gaussian basis functions?
I am attempting to write my own Hartree-Fock program, and I am currently working on implementing the STO-3G basis set for a few atoms. For C, it is of the form
C     0
S    3   1.00
      0.7161683735D+02       0.1543289673D+00
      0.1304509632D+02       0.5353281423D+00
      0.3530512160D+01       0.4446345422D+00
SP   3   1.00
      0.2941249355D+01      -0.9996722919D-01       0.1559162750D+00
      0.6834830964D+00       0.3995128261D+00       0.6076837186D+00
      0.2222899159D+00       0.7001154689D+00       0.3919573931D+00

The 1s function is of the general form
$$g_{1s}=\sum_i d_ie^{-\alpha_i r^2}$$
where the $\alpha_i$ are the first column of 3 numbers and the $d_i$ are the second column of three numbers, giving one contracted function composed of three primitives. If my own understanding is correct, the "SP" means that the 2s and the 2p orbitals share the same exponents but use different contraction coefficients (2s coefficients would be the second column while the 2p coefficients would be the third column). If this is the case then I understand that the 2s function takes the form of the 1s function above.
My question relates to the form of the 2p function. Does each primitive gaussian in the contraction correspond to px, py, pz, i.e.
$$g_{2p} = d_1 xe^{-\alpha_1 r^2}+d_2ye^{-\alpha_2 r^2}+d_3ze^{-\alpha_3 r^2}$$
so that there would be only one contracted 2p function, or are there separate contracted functions for each 2px, 2py, 2pz (i.e. $g_{2p_x}=\sum_i d_ixe^{-\alpha_i r^2}$, and similarly for 2py/2pz with the same $\alpha_i$ and $d_i$ but y/z instead of x)? This example calculation for a water molecule seems to use separate basis functions for 2px/2py/2pz with 5 total basis functions. I have so far written my program in a way that only works when the cartesian primitives making up a contracted gaussian function have the same form, which would be a bummer if this were not the case.
Thanks!

After testing my own code it appears to be the case that each 2px, 2py, and 2pz gets its own contracted basis function, each of which share the same exponents and contraction coefficients. Proceeding in this manner matches with the previously linked sample calculation for water (at least for the overlap, kinetic energy, and nuclear attraction integrals).
Edits:
For STO-3G basis set, your valence shell only have a s-type orbital and p-type orbital. Gaussian for some reason uses the same exponents for the orbitals that make up the same shell (in this case n=2). Each atom has one 2s orbital and three 2p-type orbitals ($2p_{+1},2p_0, 2p_{-1}$) and they are degenerate unless you have some perturbation that splits them. This is the reason why it makes sense to use the same contraction coefficients and exponents for the three 2p orbitals.

I gave +1 on the question, but this answer is quite short and only tells us what "appears" to be the case, without much further substance. What comparison lead you to this conclusion, and why does it appear to be the case that these get their own contracted basis function? Adding these details would make this a better answer for future viewers of this site, and also possibly for yourself if you have to look back at this some years from now and you don't quite remember what lead you to this conclusion. If my comment can be longer than your answer, it usually means the answer might be too short.
